# ORA_EXCEL save_to_file does not recognize directory path

Tags: excel, oracle, oracle11g

I have installed the ORA_EXCEL package.

When I execute a test script, TOAD won't recognize the directory path for this sample code.

```
BEGIN    
ORA_EXCEL.new_document;    
ORA_EXCEL.add_sheet('My sheet');        
ORA_EXCEL.query_to_sheet('select sysdate from dual'); -- Select data from database   
ORA_EXCEL.set_cells_filter('A1', 'K1'); -- Add cell filtering from column A1 to column K1    
ORA_EXCEL.save_to_file('D:\', 'example.xlsx'); 
END;
```

I get the following error:
*ORA-20100: Procedure save_to_file -20100 ORA-20100: Procedure blob2file -29280 ORA-29280: invalid directory path
ORA-06512: at "myschema.ORA_EXCEL", line 2734
ORA-06512: at line 6*

Would appreciate help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [the documentation](http://www.oraexcel.com/documentation/ORA_EXCEL.save_to_file), the directory name parameter is an Oracle directory object name, not an operating system directory path.

You need to create that first with the [`create directory` command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/statements_5007.htm), and then pass the directory name (not path) to the call. You need sufficient permissions to create the directory object of course, or have your DBA create it and grant read/write permissions on it to you.

So for example:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY excel_dir AS 'D:\';

BEGIN    
  ...
  ORA_EXCEL.save_to_file('EXCEL_DIR', 'example.xlsx'); 
END;
/
```